# Jfrog Pipeline -Is there any option to run all steps in the same container without deleting the container every time?

Tags: jfrog-pipelines

Steps are running in different containers. Is there any option to run all steps in the same container without deleting the container every time? I am using a SaaS instance.

Yaml Eg -
template: true   # required for local templates
valuesFilePath: ./values.yml

resources:

- name: git_repo
  type: GitRepo
  configuration:
  path: {{ .Values.repoPath }}
  branches:
  include: main
  gitProvider: {{ .Values.gitProvider }}
- name: cron_trigger_cu
  type: CronTrigger
  configuration:
  interval: '0 2 1 * *'

pipelines:

- name: TestPileline
  configuration:
  affinityGroup: myjobtasks
  jfrogCliVersion: 2
  steps:

  - name: Setupmyjob
    type: Bash
    configuration:
    affinityGroup: myjobtasks
    inputResources:
    - name: cron_trigger_cu
    - name: git_repo
    execution:
    onExecute:
    - sudo apt-get update -y
    - sudo apt-get install -y  apt-utils python3-venv
  - name: RunPolicies
    type: Bash
    configuration:
    affinityGroup: myjobtasks
    inputSteps:
    - name: Setupmyjob
    inputResources:
    - name: git_repo
    execution:
    onExecute:
    - pwd